# Bitnami Trac apache set domain name

Tags: apache, trac, bitnami

I recently installed Bitnami trac and now I want to access it using my domain name.

I've made the necessary changes to the apache config file (httpd.conf) found in C:\Bitnami\trac-1.0.5-0\apache2\conf\ directory. I've installed trac in port 8080.

So this is the only change I made.

ServerName trac.mydomain.com:8080

I had trac in another server before, and that time also this was the only change I made to get my domain work with it. But this time it doesn't work.

Can somebody please tell me where I've missed? Do I have to update any other place?

Comment: Please specify *exactly* what you mean by "it doesn't work".  Do you get a specific error in the Apache logs?  Do requests time out and get no response whatsoever?  Something else?

Comment: When I enter the domain, it keeps loading..and finally nothing loads..but when I connect to the vpn and access the server using my internal ip, it loads.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, you can access the server fine by using the IP address, but can't access it at all when using the domain name.  This sounds like it might not be related to Trac at all.  Here are a couple of things to try:

- Run "`nslookup your-domain-name.com`".  You should get a result that says "Addresses:" and lists your server's IP address.  If you don't (or if you get a "Non-existent domain" error), then your DNS server isn't mapping your domain name to your IP address correctly.
- Look through Apache's various log files on your server and see if there is any evidence of your request ever reaching your server.  Whenever I do this, I first change `LogLevel` to `debug` in the Apache config files so that I get as much output as possible (restart Apache after changing the config file).  If a 'debug'-level log doesn't even show that Apache saw the request, then something between your server and your local system is causing problems (a firewall perhaps).  If the Apache logs *do* show that the request made it through, then the problem is likely an Apache configuration problem and the log output should provide hints as to how to continue.
- Try connecting via VPN and then accessing your server by domain name (not IP address).  If you can access the server by IP but not by name, then the server may not know its own domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here. By default bitnami installations accept petitions from any IP so you don't have to set the ServerName.

Although, if you want your page to be accessible using trac.yourdomain.com, you should consider using apache virtualHosts, could you try to follow this documentation page?

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache#How_to_create_a_Virtual_Host.3f

Comment: Please make sure to add more information to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't make any difference :(